# Jetpack Compose - where are the selectable card overloads?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-card

I am using the `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-beta03`.

The Javadoc of the simplest card (in the `CardKt.kt` file) says

> This Card does not handle input events - see the other Card overloads if you want a clickable or selectable Card.

I do find the card with onClick, however I do not see a card which is selectable. Where is the mentioned overload?

Comment: Use the onClick attribute to put your logic. What is your final goal?

Comment: As a card wrapps a surface, I want to have the same behaviour as a Surface, where the selectable param exists....

As a workaround I have done it with onclick and custom logic...

Answer (score 1):

Currently the M3 `Card` doesn't have a `selected` parameter.
You can use something like:

```
var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .selectable(
            selected = selected,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = rememberRipple(),
            enabled = enabled,
            onClick = { /* do something */ }
        )
){
    //card content...
}
```

Comment: Another option is: `.clickable { onClick() }` modifier property